# Nette getUser in component

Tags: php, nette

I have to ask how to get name of logged user into Nette component (SomethingControl.php). Apparently I can't just do this:

```
$identity = $this->getUser()->getIdentity();
if ($identity) $this->template->username = $identity->getData()['username'];
```

So I've tried this:

```
$this->template->username = $this->user
```

but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot get user like this, because `UI\Control` is not descendant of [UI\Presenter](https://api.nette.org/2.4/source-Application.UI.Presenter.php.html#1396-1405). But `Nette\Security\User` is service registered in DIC so you can get it like this:

```
class SomethingControl extends \Nette\Application\UI\Control
{

    /**
     * @var \Nette\Security\User
     */
    private $user;

    public function __construct(\Nette\Security\User $user)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        bdump($this->user); // getIdentity and username
    }

}
```

Just make sure that you are using [Component Factory](https://doc.nette.org/en/2.4/di-usage#toc-component-factory) - means do not create your component in the presenter using `new` operator.

Comment: As far as I know - yes it does.

Comment: It returns error Call to undefined function App\MainModule\Components\bdump()

Comment: Oh, I am sorry it's 2.4. You can use just `dump` or `\Tracy\Debugger::barDump(...)`. See: https://api.nette.org/2.3/source-Tracy.Debugger.php.html#523-545. But it's just dump so you can debug what is in `$this->user`.

Comment: Is there a better way?

Comment: Using dependency injection is the best way you can do it.